# Iterate a nested dictionary and filter specific fields

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, nested-loops

I have an example object which is mixed of lists and dicts:

```
{
    "field_1" : "aaa",
    "field_2": [
        {
        "name" : "bbb",
          .....
        "field_4" : "ccc",
        "field_need_to_filter" : False,
        },

        {
        "name" : "ddd",
          .....
        "details": [
            {
            "name" : "eee",
            ....
            "details" : [
                {
                "name": "fff",
                .....
                "field_10": {
                    "field_11": "rrr",
                    ...
                    "details": [
                        {
                        "name": "xxx",
                        ...
                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "name": "yyy",
                        ...
                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "field_13": "zzz",
                        ...
                        "field_need_to_filter": False,
                        }
                                ]
                                }
                },


        ]}]}

       ]
}
```

I'd like to iterate this dictionary and add all the corresponding fields for `name` where `field_need_to_filter` is `True`, so for this example, expected output would be:
`["ddd.eee.fff.xxx", "ddd.eee.fff.yyy"]`. I've been looking at this for too long and my brain stops working now, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is essentially a tree traversal problem where the tree can have N nodes (objects in a list in this case). What you'd want to do is, while traversing your tree, keep track of the path you've used to reach the given node, and if that node contains `field_need_to_filter: True`, add the path + field name to your list of valid paths.

Comment: Which means a recursive function would be a good idea.

Comment: hi i updated my question and added some example code that i tried, i'm not very familiar with recursive functions, that code seems not iterating...

Comment: It's a little complicated to code, since as you dig into your dictionary you can get a list, a dictionary or a simple value; I managed to do it by separating these 3 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took me some time to think about the different cases and fix bugs, but this works (at least on your example of dict); note that it assumes that dicts containing "field_need_to_filter": True are end-points (the function doesn't delve deeper into those)). I'll be glad to add explanations to the code if you want some.

```
mydict = {
    "field_1" : "aaa",
    "field_2": [
        {
        "name" : "bbb",

        "field_4" : "ccc",
        "field_need_to_filter" : False,
        },

        {
        "name" : "ddd",

        "details": [
            {
            "name" : "eee",

            "details" : [
                {
                "name": "fff",

                "field_10": {
                    "field_11": "rrr",

                    "details": [
                        {
                        "name": "xxx",

                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "name": "yyy",

                        "field_need_to_filter": True,
                        },
                        {
                        "field_13": "zzz",

                        "field_need_to_filter": False,
                        }
                                ]
                                }
                },


        ]}]}

       ]
}

def filter_paths(thing, path=''):
    if type(thing) == dict:
        # if this dict has a name, log it
        if thing.get("name"):
            path += ('.' if path else '')  + thing["name"]
        # if this dict has "...filter": True, we've reached an end point, and return the path
        if thing.get("field_need_to_filter") and thing["field_need_to_filter"]:
            return [path]
        # else we delve deeper
        result = []
        for key in thing:
            result += [deep_path for deep_path in filter_paths(thing[key], path)]
        return result
    
    # if the current object is a list, we simply delve deeper
    elif type(thing) == list:
        result = []
        for element in thing:
            result += [deep_path for deep_path in filter_paths(element, path)]
        return result

    # We've reached a dead-end, so we return an empty list
    else:
        return []
        
filter_paths(mydict)
# Out[204]: ['ddd.eee.fff.xxx', 'ddd.eee.fff.yyy']
```

Comment: Hi @Swifty thanks, the strings in the output list contain an extra dot in the beginning, instead of 'ddd.eee', it's '.ddd.eee', I know I can do slice on the result but is there a neater way to make it 'ddd.eee' ?

Comment: Oh indeed, I hadn't even noticed this! Fixed by adding the '.' only if path is already filled ( path += ('.' if path else '')  + thing["name"]  ).

Answer (score -1):

If that is your correct code, the you call iterate_fun instead of iterate_func after the check for field name of ddd

Comment: Hi it's just a typo:)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).